# Incorrect syntax near 'and'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

string query1 = "Select * from client_rewards where client_id=" + Session["companyId"] + "and program_code=" + TextBoxProgram_Code_Merchant.Text + "and reward_code=" + TextBoxReward_Code_Merchant.Text;

Answer (score 3):

**No**, ASP.net is mainly used for producing dynamic pages which have html. It could be used to make a site which does not have database.

> ASP.NET is a server-side Web application framework designed for Web
>   development to produce dynamic Web pages. It was developed by
>   Microsoft to allow programmers to build dynamic web sites, web
>   applications and web services, [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)

Answer (score 1):

> Is ASP.net mainly used for connecting to a database?

Well, *yes*, but only because most applications that exist interact with data *in some way*, and one of the more common ways to store any non-trivial data is: in a database. So - one way or another, most applications of *any* kind interact (directly or indirectly) with a database.

You are not *required* to interact with a database, nor indeed with any external service. If you don't need those things: that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been developing your web application in ASP.NET then creating data adapters to interact with a database is not difficult.